# Scroll view cuts off?

Tags: objective-c

My scroll view does this for some reason, does it have to do with constraints? Having trouble what could be causing this. It's only after I press return after a few times. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

EDIT: 
Basically, when the cursor gets past a certain point on the text view, instead of scrolling down even more on the text view, the cursor starts scrolling down further into the view. However, in my storyboard, the TextView takes up the whole space. I'm using TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.

Comment: scrollview does this?does what?

Comment: Please make your question more descriptive.

Comment: Sorry about that, updated.